# Infinite recursion error

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion, subclass, overriding

I have a parent class which has the following method in it:

```
public String getSubjects() {
    return this.getSubjects();    
}
```

And in the subclass which inherits this method is the following:

```
@Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Computer Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "] " + name + ": "); 
    }
```

But I get an error saying:

```
The method getSubjects may recurse if not overridden in subclass.
```

What does this mean and what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent's class' implementation just calls itself, and as the error notes, will continue to do so, endlessly. The parent class should either return some default (e.g., `null`), or, even better, leave this method `abstract` if there's no intelligent way it can implement the method.

Answer (score 0):

this.getSubjects() refer to the current method. If you want to call the method of the parent class, user keyword "super" :

```
public String getSubjects() {
    return super.getSubjects();    
}
```